# how to bind selected users

Tags: jquery

I used this code to select top 5 users from jQuery grid on button click.

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]:lt(5)').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Its working fine if I click the button it checks the check boxes.  After checking any box, there is another button to send the selected user to the other page, if not pop up message to select at least one user...

The above code I implemented checks the boxes fine, but if I click send it pops up the select a user message.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you post the code you have for the "submission button" as well please?

Comment: Well, if you want to in the darkness bind them, you could use that one ring.

Comment: @kumar: he's pulling your leg.  @OMG Unicorns: +1 lol.

Comment: I have a selection of users I wouldn't mind binding myself. . .

Comment: you need to post the other code from wich the popup message start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ageba3

you need to have something like this:

assuming `#send` is your send button!

```
 $('#send').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( $('#Grid input:checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
         //open popup
        } else {
        //do nothing
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#anotherButton').click(function() {
    if( $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]:checked').length ) {
        // At least one is checked
    } else {
        // None are checked
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Reversed the logic. Not sure why I decided to negate the first time.

Comment: nice implementation `$('#Grid input[type=checkbox]:checked').length`